# Case Assignment

Tags: case, assignment-rules

In my company if any user creates a case, the admin should be assigned to that case automatically. I am trying to figure out a way to do it, but I couldn't.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Case Assignment Rules for this.  You would set up a rule that assigns all cases to the admin.  Once you have the rule set up, I would change all your case layouts so that the 'Assign using active assignment rules' checkbox is checked by default.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_assignment_rules.htm&language=en_US

[image]

Comment: No worries, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a **case assignment rule** with one rule entry like this

[image: Assignment rule entry]

2. Make sure you **activate** the assignment rule
3. Make sure your case page layout has the case assignment checkbox as **'Show on edit page'** (can be found under 'Layout Properties')

[image: Layout properties]

4. Whenever a user creates a case, have them make sure that checkbox is checked (you can set it to `true` by default as well)

Alternatively, you could do this with a **workflow rule + field update** where you update the owner for all cases to your admin on creation. This eliminates the need of the checkbox that needs to be set to `true`, but gives your users no flexibility to not reassign the case (looks like this would not be an issue given your description).